# Ubuntu MATE 14.04: Skype font, mouse and look bug

Tags: 14.04, fonts, skype, lts, mate

i recently installed Ubuntu MATE 14.04 on my computer, I want have skype but this happend:

[image: Mouse also changed (old ugly black kde mouse)]

(Mouse also changed (old ugly black kde mouse)).

Any solution to fix this bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have exactly same problem and this solution worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386
```

<sub>[Source](http://simionbaws.ro/linux/fix-ugly-skype-theme-on-ubuntu-14-04/)</sub>